# Show only all paragraphs in jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to learn jquery, so I'm attempting to write a script that'll hide most things on a page, leaving (for now) only the paragraphs.

```
(function() {
  var all = $("*");
  all.hide();

  var paragraphs = $("p");
  paragraphs.show();
 })();
```

That is the code I have now, but it doesn't work. It hides everything, but it doesn't show the paragraphs afterwards. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: All para will be hidden If the para's parent is hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution for a start:

```
$("body :not(p)").hide();
```

Read it as: in `<body>` element *find* all elements that are *not* `<p>`.

I suspect your markup is quite simple with minimum of nested elements, e.g.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1</p>
    <div>Text block</div>
    <p>Paragraph 2</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Otherwise, as noted in the other answers (and comments), you should consider if your `<p>` elements do have non-`<p>` parents. In such cases nested paragraphs might remain invisible.

Comment: All para will be hidden If the para's parent is hidden.

Comment: @Vega It's DOM tree. You know how problematic is to show elements which parent is hidden.

Comment: @VisioN, "you know how problematic...", it's not problematic at all.

Comment: @zzzzBov C'mon. For `<div><p></p></div>` how can you hide `<div>` and set `<p>` visible?

Comment: @VisioN Yes it is.. I wonder why he would want to do that.. btw.. I didn't dv as I understand how problematic it is

Comment: @VisioN, he only said he wanted to "hide most things". Requirements being what they are, the parent's of the `<p>` elements must be visible.

Comment: "*the parent's of the `<p>` elements must be visible*", where have you found that? What if the DOM is as simple as `<body><div></div><p></p><h3></h3></body>`? The OP is learning jQuery, I doubt if he really needs that complicated solution now.

Comment: @Vega Maybe we *slightly* overcomplicate the task.

Comment: @VisioN, `<html>` and `<body>` are also parents of `<p>` elements, and *must be visible*.

Answer (score 2):

You can't show children of a hidden parent. What you're trying to do can't work. You'll have to make sure the ancestors of the `<p>` tags are all visible, all the way up to `<body>` and `<html>`.

As a work-around, you can detach all `<p>` tags from their parents, hide everything left inside the body and reattach the `<p>` directly to the body. Your dom will be irreversibly broken at this point, as far as restoring its original state.

```
var paragraphs = $('p').detach();

$('body *').hide();

$('body').append(paragraphs);
```

I can't think of any practical use for this. You probably need to rethink what you're trying to do and change your markup to accomodate your new knowledge.

Comment: Perhaps I should just explain what I'm trying to do. I want to write a script that'll clean up news pages. Get rid of the sidebars, ads, header, just leave you with the headlines and paragraphs and lists and stuff.

Comment: Then you probably want to parse the HTML, extract the useful bits, store them some place, and then render a completely new page with the content you want.

Comment: So it couldn't be done with jQuery, if the pages are on separate domains. It would need to be done server side?

Answer (score 1):

Hiding everything also hides all parent elements of each `<p>`, including `<html>` and `<body>`. You'll need to make sure they're visible if the `<p>` element is to be visible.

Instead, show the paragraphs and their parents:

```
$('*').hide();
$('p').parents().andSelf().show();
```

Or, only hide elements that don't contain paragraphs:

```
$(':not(:has(p), p)').hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body :not(p)').hide();
$('body p').appendTo('body');
```

hide everything except paragraphs, then move the paragraphs to be direct children of the body.

note that "appendTo" and other methods do *not* actually clone the elements, but just move them if they already exist in the DOM.

Comment: That may mess up the layout and other.. and it is irreversible if you want to show other elements

Comment: @Vega: Indeed. Depends what your goals are. I've done something similar for thumbnails for a greasemonkey script...gets rid of all the clutter on the page. Of course, if that's the case I'd probably `.remove()` the elements instead.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is even if the Paragraphs are visible , The `body` which encases them is still hidden.. So you won't see the paragraphs even if you make them visible.. because the **parent which is the body** is also hidden..

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the `*` wildcard is including `<body>` . Try:

```
$("body *").hide();
$("p").show().parents().show();
```

As pointed out by MarcB in the comments, you need to `.show()` all of the `<p>` parents, too (which is what `.parents().show()` does)

Comment: won't help if the p's parent is hidden.

Answer (score 0):

P will not be shown if its parents are hidden.

```
(function() {
  var all = $("body *").not("p");
  all.hide();
 })();
```

If you want to show all p but hide others you can append all p to body as:

```
(function() {
  var all = $("body *").not("p");
  all.hide();
   $("p").appendTo('body');
 })();
```